# DC circuit works well and AC does not

Tags: ac, ac-dc

I have the following circuit that consists of a power supply that, despite the redundancy, powers a 12V lamp and an arduino with 4 solid state relays. I do the tests with a direct current laboratory source, in this I send up to 27V and it does not consume more than 300ma. and it works excellent, the problem is when I connect it to a 24v alternating current transformer, where it detects that it consumes more than 2.8AMP (almost 10x more) and ends up after several seconds burning the integrated LM2576 switch, as well as even the arduino.

It is striking that it works well with direct current and not with alternating current, I have my doubts if the capacitors in alternating current can accumulate more voltage or something, but I do not understand why I have such a high consumption with the transformer compared to the source of laboratory.

[image]

Comment: where are you applying the AC?

Comment: Are you using a voltage transformer as a supply, or are you actually using a current transformer to measure current?

Comment: Two things jump out: 1 uF is a very small value for a smoothing capacitor after a bridge rectifier (hundreds or thousands of uF are more usual) and the emitters of your opto isolators are connected to one of the AC supply pins where I'd normally expect them to go to GND.

Comment: I think that's just a schematic symbol mismatch; the G3MB datasheet shows they're AC/phototriacs (assuming AC is applied to terminals 7 and 8 of J2).

Comment: @vir Ah, right. I assume specifying a 15 V part number for the regulator to supply 12 V is similarly explained.

Comment: I do not see a *12V lamp*. Did you intend *an amplifier supplied with +12 V*? Why an LM2576HVT-**15**, not a LM2576HVT-**12**? 1 μF seems way low for about 5 W, as [Finbarr already pointed out](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651455/dc-circuit-works-well-and-ac-does-not#comment1731048_651455).

Comment: `it works excellent` I am surprised, considering U1B referenced to GND of its single rail supply. OTOH, I don't understand a 12 V pullup on an AC coupled signal to begin with. (wait - electret microphone?)

Comment: [`where [to apply] the AC`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651455/dc-circuit-works-well-and-ac-does-not#comment1731044_651455) J2 7&8, hopefully. I can see using either and 10 burning the bridge…